# Animating a div's apearance on mouseover in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to animate a div on mouseover. 
I just don't know how to make it fade in/appear slowly (I think we have to use the .animate function or something like that)

```
$("#logo").mouseover(function() { $("#nav").css('visibility','visible'); });
```

Will appreciate any help :)

Comment: .animate is only for custom animations. There are methods in place already to fade in, slide down, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#logo").mouseover(function() { $("#nav").fadeIn("slow"); });
```

Make sure your css has style for #nav as `display:none;`

Reference http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

[**SAMPLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/trhJe/5/)

Comment: Yes, that was taken into account before I wanted to animate the process :), Thanks

Comment: I'm trying this $("#logo").mouseover(function() { $("#nav").css('visibility','visible').fadeIn("slow"); }); but its not fading in.

Comment: @MohammedmehdiKhatau: for fadeIn to work your div must be initially displayed to none, If you are making it visible then there is no point in fadingIn, which means you are fading in an elemnt that is already on the view. which means that fadeIN effect is invisible to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#logo").mouseover(function() { 
    $("#nav").fadeIn('slow'); 
});
```

Refer Site http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fadeIn/fadeOut` methods or the `fadeToggle` method which automatically fades in or out. Every method allows a `duration` parameter to set the animation time, but there also many more parameters to modify the fading.

Look at the API for [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) to see the whole functionality (and how to use) :) . ([fadeIn API](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), [fadeOut API](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)).

Answer (score 0):

USe [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)... try this.

```
$("#nav").hide();
$("#logo").mouseover(function() { $("#nav").fadeIn(600));
```

Comment: Yes, but I also wanted the visibility of #nav to change to visible on mouse over. $("#logo").mouseover(function() { $("#nav").css('visibility','visible').fadeIn("slow"); }); but it doesnt work

Comment: you need to hide your `nav` div first.. try my update.... or just add `style="display:none;" to `nav` div

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sample</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#logo").mouseover(function() { $('div:hidden:first').fadeIn('slow', function() {
// Animation complete
alert("complete")
}); });
});

</script>
<style>
#nav{display:none}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="logo">Click Me</div>
<div id="nav" style="background:#CCC">sample</div>
</body>
</html>
```